# A popup, "Failed to automatically update constraints" pops up in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: xcode, autolayout

When I added a couple of controls in my viewcontroller in storyboard and click
 *Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to Suggested Constraints*.
The following popup appears and I cannot perform auto layout constraints.

[image]

Though, when I remove the Prototype Cell (which has a couple of labels and an imageview) from my tableview then auto layout works fine. Any thoughts?

**Edited:**
And manually adding constraints to individual elements work fine as well. After manually setting the image view inside prototype cell, the auto layout has started working fine without popping up that popup. So, maybe, sometime, it is hard for auto layout to figure out all these constraints itself.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot add constraints manually?

Comment: I am facing the same problem,while trying to add constraint to label in view,which already contains a uitableview.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've submitted a bug report to Apple and will add a solution if they get back to me.

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWsHB.png)Remove Navigation controller and try it.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing constraints before resetting them, this has worked for me before.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using prototype cells in a UITableView and some other views in a UIViewController.

My solution was to select all the elements in the prototype cell and see if these had red or orange markers (constraint conflicts/problems). These elements I cleared the constraints for and afterwards I had no problem telling the entire view to "Reset to Suggested Constraints".

Obviously, Interface Builder has a problem resetting embedded table content constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Actually . If you import different storyboard from another Xcode project. This is not possible to avoid problem. My personal advice is create a new UIViewcontroller or stroyboard. And step by step add items. But. I did not do this.

I lived three times. In fact When I saw this message. I was configuring tableview or UITableviewcell. At the end of the story I have fixed my problem. But There is no gold key for issue. I will explain as much as possible.

1. for All Views in View Controller select Clear Constraints
2. If you are using tableview or collection view. please delete.
3. I assume. there are label, button and scrollview on the project. Please add missing constraints. If you leave problem again. You need to delete any of them.
4. for All Views in View Controller Reset to Suggested constraints.
   If you don't leave problem again. PERFECT. If there is a reverse situation
5. for All Views in Second View Controller select Clear Constraints
6. delete any of item. Select add missing constraints again.

Continue to try the third and fourth steps. Until you find the faulty objects.

I'll try to help you if you submit your project.

Good luck .

Answer (score 0):

Following Solution work for me.

Actually initially i used Free-from storyboard of size 600 into 900 that time i was getting this error. so i deleted that storyboard and again drag and drop element and make connections, then i solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem with Xcode 6. In my MainViewController I have a tableview with custom TableviewCell. In Interface builder itself I have taken taken 2 labels on tableview cell.

When I try to add constraints it gives me error. I did remove prototype cell in tableview and worked with nib with customCell.  Be careful while working with custom tableViewCell.

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue last evening, After many try and error i found that it was just a corrupt ViewController. I created a new ViewController2 with the same aspects, then applied constraints to the ViewController2, and it worked! Still not sure why exactly the other one had issues.

Answer (score -1):

I had some problem with Xcode 7. I solved it very simple. I cleared constraints -

> Reset to Suggested Constrains

, then applied -

> Add Missing Constrains.

This has worked for me.

[image]